# SOAP Webservice client : jaxws-maven-plugin fails to generate the @WebServiceClient class

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, java-17, jaxws-maven-plugin

We are developing a client for a SOAP werbservice using JDK 17 and SpringBoot.

We are using jaxws-maven-plugin as described in [https://www.baeldung.com/java-soap-web-…](https://www.baeldung.com/java-soap-web-%E2%80%A6) to generate stubs for the SOAP client.

The plugin fails to generate the `@WebServiceClient` class that can be used to make the SOAP API call.

If we use JDK1.8 which comes packaged with `wsimport` utility, these classes get generated successfully. But we need to use OpenJDK 17 for project requirements.

How to resolve this issue?

I tried using below piece of code in pom.xml for maven build

```xml
<plugin>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
            <args>
                  <arg>-B-XautoNameResolution</arg>
            </args>
            <wsdlUrls>
                  <wsdlUrl>----/?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <keep>true</keep>
            <packageName>com.....</packageName>
            <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but the client class with annotation `@WebServiceClient` is not getting generated. Rest of the bean classes are generated.

Comment: Are you able to generate the WebServiceClient class for sample HelloWorld web service? If not, then provide more details to reproduce the issue - like WSDL, all classes, configs, classpath, command to generate etc. If yes, then there is some issue with your implementation. Instead of generating artifact for all, try to generate for a small portion, by simplifying the web service (by reducing logic, request response params etc).